# Привязка списка слов из файла к массиву

Tags: java

Как сделать задачу, только чтобы проще, т. е. по другому привязать слова из файла к массиву?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Dz51_4 {
    // создаёт переменные и присваивает им соотв. значения.
    static String Str, FReadPath = "C:\\Имена.txt", FWritePath = "C:\\Dz51-4.rez" ;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // читает имена из файла Имена.txt, запоняет массив MassName этими именами, сортирует массив по убыванию 
        // и записывает результат в файл Dz51-4.rez.
        try {
            BufferedReader FBufR = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (FReadPath));

            BufferedWriter FBufWr = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (FWritePath));

            // создаёт массив Mass с именами из файла Имена.txt. 
            String Mass []; // = {"Саша", "Маша", "Юля", "Даша", "Глаша", "Андрей", "Вася", "Коля", "Петя", "Костя"};

            // создаёт массив имён MassName, который надо заполнить именами.
            String MassName []; // = {"    ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "      ", "    ", "     ", "    ", "     ", "      "};

            while ((Str = FBufR.readLine()) != null){   // читает строки.
                MassName = Mass;      // заполняет массив MassName.
            } // while

            // сортирует массив имён по убыванию.
            for (int curr = 0; curr < Mass.length - 1; curr++){  // перебираем текущие ячейки.
                for (int i = curr +1; i < Mass.length; i ++){    // перебор нижестоящей ячейки.
                     if (MassName [curr].compareTo(MassName[i]) < 0){    // проверка равенства ячеек.
                     // вытеснение самой большой ячейки в ячейку Mass [curr].
                         String Buff;
                         Buff = MassName [curr];
                         MassName [curr] = MassName [i];
                         MassName [i] = Buff;
                     } // if
                } // for i
            } // for curr

            for (int i = 0; i < Mass.length; i ++){
                FBufWr.write(String.valueOf(MassName [i]) + ","); // заносит i-ую ячейку массива в файл.
            } // for i

            FBufWr.close();   // сохраняет все изменения в файле и записывает его на диск.
        } // try

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // catch

        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // catch

}
}
```

Имена даны в строке String Mass.

Comment: Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Я, лично, ничего не понял. Отредактировав вопрос, пожалуйста, сформулируйте — В чем, собственно, дело. Не куском кода, а русским языком — в чем заключается задача, и чем не устраивает приведенный код.

Comment: Преподаватель требует, чтобы привязка слов из файла была сделана по другому не так String Mass []; // = {"Саша", "Маша", "Юля", "Даша", "Глаша", "Андрей", "Вася", "Коля", "Петя", "Костя"};

            // создаёт массив имён MassName, который надо заполнить именами.
            String MassName []; // = {"    ", "     ", "     ", "     ", "      ", "    ", "     ", "    ", "     ", "      "}; а как-то более универсально. То есть привязать как-то массив к файлу с именами. Но более упрощенно.

Comment: А в чём суть задачи вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если препаду, по какой-то причине не нравиться массив, где ключами является цифры, то можно создать хеш(ака ассоциативный массив).
См. класс Hashtable
В теории, тогда будет проще управлять данными.